# How to pass parameters to Doctrine Entity Listener?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm using Doctrine2 with ZendFramework2.
I need to handle lifecycle events of some entities, like described here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html
but I also need some additional parameters in the listener, or at least Zend ServiceManager instance in order to fetch them.
Is there any way to have Zend ServiceManager in the Doctrine listener or pass some parameters to it?

```
<?php
class ProductListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'postUpdate',
        );
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args) 
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();

        // need to pass additional parameters here like
        $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into implementing ZF2's `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`. This requires your listener being instantiated through the Service Manager/Locator itself though (and the related invokable/factory declaration in your module/app's configuration), instead of directly new'ing it as shown in the examples of your link.

Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469860/implementing-servicelocatorawareinterface-dependency-for-forward-class-in-a-zf) that might help understand the magic ;)

Comment: Thanks, but the catch is that the listener is called by Doctrine rather than ZF, so this magic doesn't work for it.

Comment: You're wrong Alexey, it actually works. Listener can be retrieved by FQCN OR by Service Locator
Read the line 35 : https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Options/EventManager.php#L35